# Why is scalatest MockitoSugar deprecated?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, scalatest

I'm new to writing junit tests in Scala and I'm using Mockito to mock objects. I'm also using `scalatest_2.12-3.0.4`. The ScalaTest documentation (like [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects)) shows the syntax to create the mock using MockitoSugar, i.e.

```
val mockCollaborator = mock[Collaborator]
```

Eclipse shows `org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar` crossed out in the import statement, indicating it is deprecated. The only alternative I've found is, don't use MockitoSugar and instead do:

```
val mockCollaborator = mock(classOf[Collaborator])
```

This seems to work fine too, so I'm curious what ScalaTest is recommending me to use.

Or for that matter, why else would I use MockitoSugar? Does it have any other features? I've been unable to find any documentation about it, except that everybody seems to use the shorthand `mock[]` notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base on the [issue](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/1789) and some comments, the answer should be changed：

1. the `MockitoSugar` has been moved to a separate project: https://github.com/scalatest/scalatestplus-mockito
2. need to add a new dependency to use it

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatestplus/mockito-3-4_2.13/3.3.0.0-SNAP3

```
testCompile group: 'org.scalatestplus', name: 'mockito-3-4_2.13', version: '3.3.0.0-SNAP3'
```

origin issue: https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/1789

---

As reported in the [source](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/release-3.0.4/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/mock/package.scala#L38) you should use `org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar` instead of `org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar`

Comment: In version 3.0.6 the class has been moved again, to `org.scalatestplus.mockito.MockitoSugar`

Comment: It has now been moved also to other dependency. See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatestplus/scalatestplus-mockito_2.13/1.0.0-M2

Comment: yeah check this issue: https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/1789
I think we should update this answer