# Do I always need `when/thenReturn` for mock object's functions

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am writing a test in Scala where I do something like this --

```
val svc = mock[Service]
Initializer.fun1(svc)
```

`fun1` internally calls a function `svc.fun2` which returns `Unit`.
My test is failing when it tries to execute `svc.fun2` with this error -

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.invocation.ArgumentsProcessor.expandArgs
```

As svc has already been mocked, I shouldn't have to mock `fun2` ,right ?
Unless I want `fun2` to return a specific value

Same thing worked for another codebase of mine, but that's using a different library for Mockito

Update :
I also tried adding a `when/thenReturn` for `fun2` but still getting the same error.
I just did this

```
when(svc.fun2()) thenReturn()
```

since it's supposed to return `UNIT`

Comment: I could not reproduce that. Which `mock` are you using? What's its namespace?

Comment: org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar

Comment: This namespace is deprecated. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/48552339/2359227 . Can you please try to upgrade the scalatest package you are using and try again?